# SQL How to get a count from the result of a formula in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that provide the number of Year between 2 dates and call it Covg as a title in the query

```
select PLANS,DATEDIFF(YEAR, STARTDT, EXPDT) Covg
from PA
```

This is working and provide something like

```
Plans       Covg
Payback     5
Standard    3
Payback     5
Payback     3
etc.
```

However, this is the result by customer. I need to know how many customers have a "covg" of 1y,2y,3y,4 years, etc. by plans
When I'm trying to add a Count for the Covg  I get the message that Covg is not a column. This is true because it's a result of a formula

How can I do this?
The results should give me something like this example

```
              (Yrs)          #Of customers with the covg
PLANS          Covg       TL_Count
Payback        1               123
Payback        2               56
Standard       1               24
Standard       3               48
Standard       5               325
```

**The last query I tried and get the error was**

```
SELECT PLANS, DATEDIFF(year,STARTDT,EXPDT) COVG, COUNT(*)TL_Count
FROM PA
Group by PLANS, TL_Count
```

Comment: If your first query is working, you are using SQL Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `GROUP BY` to this:

```
SELECT PLANS, DATEDIFF(year,STARTDT,EXPDT) COVG, COUNT(*) TL_Count
FROM PA
GROUP BY PLANS, DATEDIFF(year,STARTDT,EXPDT)
```

You need your date function in the grouping, but not the `COUNT()` as it's an aggregation already.

Comment: `DATEDIFF` in MySQL takes 2 arguments..not 3 like in SQL Server.

Comment: @vkp OP is either using SQL Server or a very old version of MySQL, but he said that part is working so I left it.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. Sorry about the SQL version. I told you I'm new in SQL. I have the free version of "SQL Server 2008 R2"

Comment: @MarioOuimet No problem, also please upvote and mark answers as correct if they answer your question.  Myself and other users of the site greatly appreciate it, and it will let future visitors know what the correct answer is. :)